# Outlook 2016 Retrieve email attachments from enterprise vault

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, enterprise

I have got email object and also attachment by using

Mail.attachments.count but archived email is not working because it is using enterprise vault.

I am getting attachments but archived email is not working and giving 0 or 1 count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through the body of the emails and found that when an email is archived, the attachments are shown either in two ways as below.

***1st***

```
<<Attachments data>>
```

***2nd***

```
Attachments:
Attachments data
```

In order to get the attachments, the below logic can be used:

```
if(strEmailBody!=null && strEmailBody.LastIndexOf("<<") != -1 && strEmailBody.LastIndexOf(">>") != -1)
{
    iStartIndex = strEmailBody.LastIndexOf("<<") + 2;

    iLastIndex = strEmailBody.LastIndexOf(">>") - 2;
    string strAttachmentsData = strEmailBody.Substring(iStartIndex, iLastIndex - iStartIndex);
    var regexObj = new Regex(@".*\)");
    var allMatchResults = regexObj.Matches(strAttachmentsData);
}
else if(strEmailBody != null &&  strEmailBody.LastIndexOf("Attachments:")!=-1)
{
    iStartIndex = strEmailBody.LastIndexOf("Attachments:") + 12;                                    
    string strAttachmentsData = strEmailBody.Substring(iStartIndex, strEmailBody.Length - iStartIndex-1);
    MatchCollection allMatchResults = null;
    var regexObj = new Regex(@".*\)");
    allMatchResults = regexObj.Matches(strAttachmentsData);
}
```